Dynamic illumination of terrain by game object with emission material
Is it possible to have a game object (I have written my own shader for this, which creates a dynamically changing colour gradient with bloom) radiate onto the terrain?
I just can't get it to work dynamically, only statically with baking.
Using Unity 6 with URP
